# Deploying to SSIS catalog and get permissions error

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis, deployment

When I attempt to deploy to SSIS 2012 Catalog on new server I get an error.  I have researched it on the web for several hours and all of the information available online does not fix my issue.
[image]

Comment: William,
What were the AD rights that fixed the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't capture the rights change that solved this issue, but it was something in a group policy that was set at a higher level that overwrote permissions to the catalog that were set by the install... i.e. fresh install or repair set the permission correctly, then on reboot of the machine, the AD group policy would get applied and the permissions would be overwritten and I got the error above.

Comment: this link may help?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213130(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up finding an article that mentioned fixing this by running a repair on the Sql Server install. When this was run, the problem was solved, temporarily.   The root cause was a group policy that was overwriting the permission needed... repair fixed the permission until the next group policy update, then it would break again.  Once we identified the group policy and fixed it, the problem went away.

Comment: William, thanks for sharing this. I ran into the same issue and nothing else on the web that I researched worked.... until I saw your solution. Though I still wonder what it is about running the repair that corrected the issue. Anyway, thank you for saving us from more frustration going forward with SQL/SSIS 2012.

Comment: I'm still dealing with this, a repair fixes the issue, but it appears that a restart of services undoes the fix.  I have an issue open with microsoft and will share more when I get a permanent fix.

Comment: Realized that I didn't update this after the final fix...  It turned out to be conflicting group policies... a group policy was overwriting permissions at a higher level in Active Directory.  The AD guys fixed the group policy and the problem went away.  I no longer work at that job, so I can't look up exactly which policy this was, sorry!